# _rb_ary_new_from_values psych.bundle Ruby Error

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm getting this error upon trying to run an app in the terminal:

```
    dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_ary_new_from_values
        Referenced from: /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/psych-2.0.17/lib/psych.bundle
        Expected in: flat namespace

    dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_ary_new_from_values
        Referenced from: /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/psych-2.0.17/lib/psych.bundle
        Expected in: flat namespace

    Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Ruby 2.2.3 is default and use in the latest RVM (get stable).  Other apps that I know work, are not working and get the same result.  I'm thinking this is either a bad gem or an RVM issue.  It's happened a handful of times before.  Not sure if I'm on a bad version of Ruby (OSX) or not.

Any help appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: It looks like there is a version mismatch somewhere. [`ruby_ary_new_from_values` only exists in 2.1 onwards](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/1c5cdc62cc34a92ae612beeb5fd9f12abaf5e6f6), so if you are somehow running the OSX system Ruby (2.0.0) with the 2.2.3 gems you might get this sort of error. I’d double check the version of Ruby you’re running is the one you think it is.

Comment: ruby -v brings up 2.0.0 for some reason.  This is an RVM issue?

Comment: Does a simple `rvm use 2.2.3` fix it? If not you probably need to provide more info about what’s going on (e.g. how you launch the app). I suspect it could be caused by RVM and Bundler interacting in some way.

Comment: Nope.  The app is launched via `ruby app.rb`.  The app is `include 'pg'`.  I'll chase up RVM as it's reporting the wrong ruby.  Cheers